# What is the computational cost of finding an element in a sorted array

Tags: time-complexity

Say that I have an array of size n that has been sorted using Quicksort e.g. X= [1,2,3,6,7]. I want to match all the values in this array with n values in another array that has a random order e.g. Y= [3,7,6,2,1].

I can iterate through each element of Y and compare it to the middle value of X i.e 3 so I would only need to complete at most n/2 checks. What would be the total computational complexity of doing this for all values of Y? I am looking for a tight bound.

Comment: Binary search in a sorted array is *O(log n)*. And as you have to do this for *n* elements , the total complexity is *O(n * log n)*

Comment: That makes sense. Then the best case would be O(n) right because it would be O(1) for each element and there are n elements?

Comment: Also, before I find the matching values in both arrays, I have sorted array X using quicksort which has a run time average complexity of Theta(nlogn) as well. If I do quicksort and search for matching values in the same array would the overall complexity still be theta(nlogn) ?

Comment: Yes because O(2 * n * log n)  (ie once for sorting, once for searching) is still O(n * log n).